# SIGSEGV after Glib::RefPtr goes out of scope?

Tags: c++, webkit, gtk, glib, gtkmm

I have this bit of code, which is working fine:

```
WebKit::WebView web;
// later:
{
    Glib::RefPtr<WebKit::WebSettings> settings = WebKit::WebSettings::create();
    // do some stuff to the object
    web.set_settings(settings);
}
```

At some later time, when `web` is still in scope but `settings` has fallen out of scope, I do the following:

```
Glib::RefPtr<WebKit::WebSettings> settings = web.get_settings();
```

This *should* recover the original settings object created above.  However what actually happens is that I get a SIGSEGV in `Glib::wrap_auto` (called from `get_settings`), with the following output:

```
GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_get_qdata: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

My assumption is that somehow when the first `settings` pointer fell out of scope it destroyed the underlying object, despite that being assigned to a property of another object.  Why is that happening?  Presumably I'm doing something wrong above, but the code seems sane to me.  (I'm presuming that assigning an object to a property would increase the C object's reference count.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's quite possibly a bug in the binding.  You should report it.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be.  I've recently been messing with updating the bindings to fix this issue as well as include new webkit features otherwise missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. No idea if it will work or not :P

```
{
   Glib::RefPtr<WebKit::WebSettings> *settings = new WebKit::WebSettings::create();
   // do some stuff to the object (use -> instead of . since it's a pointer)
   web.set_settings(*settings); // dereference the pointer
}

// later
Glib::RefPtr<WebKit::WebSettings> settings = web.get_settings();
```

Reason I *think* this will work is because making settings a pointer will allocate the storage on the heap, and the pointer will go out of scope, but the object itself will not. I could be wrong though, this is simply a C++ programmer's guess, I have no experience with any of the stuff you're working with (webkit, gtk, etc).